# leaflet-kml loads entire KML of 15-20 MB at client browser in one go or in chunks as and when user drags to other locations of country?

Tags: leaflet, kml, leaflet-plugins

I am trying Leaflet KML plugin as below:

https://github.com/windycom/leaflet-kml

Here is full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="./L.KML.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh" id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Make basemap
        const map = new L.Map('map', { center: new L.LatLng(28.412, 77.317), zoom: 11 });
        const osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

    map.addLayer(osm);

    // Load kml file
    fetch('assets/TestKml.kml')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(kmltext => {
            // Create new kml overlay
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext, 'text/xml');
            const track = new L.KML(kml);
            map.addLayer(track);

            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds();
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
</script>
```

I have KML file of my whole country that size around 15-20 MB. As the code shows the way I loaded KML, I have a doubt that the map gets downloaded and load full KML of 15-20 MB on user's browser side in one go or the KML loads in chunks as and when user drags to other locations of country. I don't want KML to be loaded entirely in one go and slow down loading at browser side. Is it possible to load in chunks as and when user drags map to other locations of country?

Comment: No, loading .kml file in chunks as needed is not possible. You would have to convert .kml file/layer to vector tiles (see https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/) and host them on your server.

Comment: @TomazicM
Will it work with open street map or do i need to host open street tiles on my own server?